# Pixel vs Percentige at Mobile env

Tags: mobile, size, kivy, screen-resolution

Im currently building fps-like game for android environment.

I had notice that if I make object with use of pixel low resolution devices can play game so easy than hight resolution phones.

If I use percentage for building objects this time bigger devices gain advantage. Such as Tablets have great size than phones and they can shot my object easly.

I want my objects exact same size on every device is it possible?

More specificly I use python-kivy is it possible to define object as cm/ft or etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a relative_size and relative_position method. And make them relative to the windows width or height.
You get the size of the window from the Window class.
Remember only to make the objects size (w,h) relative to only one of width or height. Or your objects will be warped.

```py
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Canvas,InstructionGroup,Color,Ellipse
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App


class MyCanvas(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyCanvas,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #Window.size = (200,100)

        self.size = Window.size

        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.ball = InstructionGroup()

        self.ball_size = self.relative_size(10,10)

        self.color = Color(0, 1, 1)
        self.ellipse = Ellipse(size=self.ball_size,pos=self.relative_position(100,50,self.ball_size))

        self.ball.add(self.color)
        self.ball.add(self.ellipse)

        self.canvas.add(self.ball)


    def relative_position(self,x,y,obj_size=(0,0)): # pass obj_size if you want the position to be the center of the object11
        x = ( self.width / 100.0 ) * x  - obj_size[0]/2.0
        y = ( self.height / 100.0 ) * y - obj_size[1]/2-.0
        return (x,y)


    def relative_size(self,w,h):
        return (self.width/float(w),self.width/float(h)) # only make it relative to your width or heigh
                                                         # or your object will be warped


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyCanvas()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

The relative_position method here will now be a percantage. So you pass from 0-100 in both directions. If you want something else, change the 100s in tht method.
Try to uncomment the `#Window.size = (200,100)` and play with the window size, and see how it works.
You could also make an event if your application changes size, like if your phone changes orientation.
As I did not make that, this will only work for the size the application started with.